# Remove multiplicative constant A in equation A*f(x)=0

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to find x in the equation A*f(x)=0 for A>0. Since A is a very large expression, I would save time by solving f(x)=0 instead. Is there a way to let Mathematica "cancel out A" (even if it is an expression that not explicitly specified)?

Note that FullSimplify does not do this job correctly (and certainly not fast enough)

Example:

```
Solve[(Q (-1 + A + Sqrt[x]))/B == 0]
```

I would like to obtain the expression (without manual inspection):

```
A + Sqrt[x] == 1
```

Comment: you can use `Replace` to eliminate `A`, like `Replace[A[y] f[x], A[y] f[x] -> f[x]]`

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that A is big, unknown expression. The replacement rule would therefore not work...

Comment: A few example expressions will be helpful.

Comment: What about `a + b + b x == 0`?  Do you expect this to be transformed to `a/b + 1 + x == 0`?  My point is that it is not clear when a factor should be divided out.  In your example `Q` and `B` disappear completely, so it is a very specific case.  What are your criteria for deciding what to divide out?  I'm just trying to make the question more objective and concrete.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Key importance to me is to generate an equation that can simply be executed as fast as possible.

Comment: Can you give an example which is too slow to solve?  This will help test.  For your example, you could do something like `dropIndependentTerms[expr_, x_] := drop[Factor[expr], x];
drop[terms__Times, x_] := DeleteCases[terms, _?(FreeQ[x])]` Then `dropIndependentTerms[expr, x]` where `expr = (Q (-1 + A + Sqrt[x]))/B`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Wouldn't `Factor` attempt to factor the `A` in `A f[x]`? I believe that is not desired (perhaps something like `drop[Factor[drop[expr]], x]` would work?)

Comment: @JHM I do not understand, I thought the whole point was to get rid of `A` in `A f[x]` and end up with `f[x]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I mean that if `expr` is not fully factored (let's say `a (b x + b c)`), then `a` would be factored before being dropped. It could be dropped before the factorisation.

Comment: @JHM Sorry, I still don't understand.  Isn't the desired solution for `a (b x + b c)` simply `x + c`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Misread the question. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
Select[((Q (-1 + A + Sqrt[x]))/B == 0)[[1]], Not[FreeQ[#, x]] &] == 0

(* -1 + A + Sqrt[x] == 0 *)
```

Then you could put the output into `Solve`.

Or, more generally:

```
SetAttributes[extractfx, HoldAll];
extractfx[eq_, sym_Symbol] := Select[eq[[1]], Not[FreeQ[#, sym]] &] == 0;
```

which yields:

```
extractfx[(Q (-1 + A + Sqrt[x]))/B == 0, x]

(* -1 + A + Sqrt[x] == 0 *)
```

Note that the above code works only when the LHS has some multiplication at the outmost level and contains your variable, and the RHS is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional parameter of `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to specify assumptions. $A f(x)=0$ only simplifies to $f(x)=0$ when $A\ne0$, so we can just use that assumption:

```
Simplify[A*f[x]==0,A!=0]
```

And of course you can specify a list of assumptions as well:

```
Simplify[(Q (-1 + A + Sqrt[x]))/B == 0, {Q!=0, B!=0}]
```

See the [full documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html?q=Simplify) for `Simplify`.

Comment: That does not prevent the evaluation of `A`.