# Collecting terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Here is my issue. I am posting because I did not find a direct answer anywhere. I have a bunch of terms which I obtain by `Expand[]` of a product. The result contains terms like (`a`, `b` are const):

```
0.5 b x^2 Cos[a]^3 Cos[x^2/2] FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]]

Sqrt[b] x Cos[a]^2 Cos[x^2/2]^2 FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] Sin[a]

0.5 Cos[a] Cos[x^2/2]^3 Sin[a]^2

Cos[a]^2 Sin[a] Sin[x^2/2]
```

and so on - you get the idea (hopefully). For each of these (and the rest - there are ~200 terms altogether) there are a few of them with different coefficients. I want to gather terms with identical x-dependence together, but `Group[]` only works for polynomials. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: My original product which I want to expand and group is as follows:

```
Exprpos[x_] = (-(1/2)*Cos[a]*Cos[x^2/2] + (1/2)*Sin[a]*
      Sin[x^2/2])*(Sqrt[b]*x*Cos[a]*FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] - (1/2)*
       Sqrt[b]*Cos[a]*x - 
      Sqrt[b]*Sin[a]*x*FresnelS[x/Sqrt[b]] + (1/2)*Sqrt[b]*Sin[a]*x - 
      Cos[a]*Sin[x^2/2] - Sin[a]*Cos[x^2/2] + Sin[a])^2 - (Cos[a]*
      Sin[x^2/2] + 
     Sin[a]*Cos[x^2/2])*((1/2)*b*Cos[a]*Cos[a]*FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]]*
      FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] - (1/2)*b*Cos[a]*Cos[a]*
      FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] + (b/8)*Cos[a]*Cos[a] + (1/2)*b*Sin[a]*
      Sin[a]*FresnelS[x/Sqrt[b]]*FresnelS[x/Sqrt[b]] - (1/2)*b*Sin[a]*
      Sin[a]*FresnelS[x/Sqrt[b]] + (b/8)*Sin[a]*Sin[a] - 
     Sqrt[b]*Sin[a]*Sin[a]*x*FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] - 
     b*Sin[a]*
      Cos[a] (FresnelS[x/Sqrt[b]]*FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] - (1/2)*
         FresnelS[x/Sqrt[b]] - (1/2)*
         FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] + (1/4)) + (1/2)*Sqrt[b]*Sin[a]*Sin[a]*
      x - Sin[a]*Cos[2 a]*Cos[x^2/2] + Sin[a]*Sin[2 a]*Sin[x^2/2] + 
     Sin[a]*Cos[2 a] - 
     Sqrt[b]*Sin[a]*Cos[a]*x*FresnelS[x/Sqrt[b]] + (1/2)*Sqrt[b]*
      Sin[a]*Cos[a]*x + (1/2)*Cos[2*a] Sin[x^2] + (1/2)*
      Sin[2*a] Cos[x^2] - (1/2)*Sin[2*a] - 
     Sqrt[b/2]*Cos[2*a]*x*FresnelC[Sqrt[2/b] x] + (1/2)*Sqrt[b/2]*
      Cos[2 a]*x + 
     Sqrt[b/2]*Sin[2*a]*x*FresnelS[Sqrt[2/b] x] - (1/2)*Sqrt[b/2]*
      Sin[2 a]*x)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127267/22013).

Comment: For future reference, you can format code by indenting a line with four spaces, wrapping code in grave accents, or highlighting code and selecting the `{}` button.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to [JHM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124691/7312):

Suppose your list of terms is `f`:

```
f = 0.5 b x^2 Cos[a]^3 Cos[x^2/2] FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] + 
   3 c x^2 Cos[a]^3 Cos[x^2/2] FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] + 
   Sqrt[b] x Cos[a]^2 Cos[x^2/2]^2 FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] Sin[a] + 
   0.5 Cos[a] Sin[x^2/2] Sin[a]^2 + Cos[a]^2 Sin[a] Sin[x^2/2];
```

First run `f=Expand[f]`, to be sure.

We can construct a function `xterms` which selects which subparts of the parts of the function contain `x`:

```
xterms[eq_] := Select[eq, Not[FreeQ[#, x]] &]
flistDD = Reverse@Sort@
  DeleteDuplicates@(flist = Table[xterms[f[[i]]], {i, Length[f]}])
```

> `{x^2 Cos[x^2/2] FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]], 
>    x Cos[x^2/2]^2 FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]], Sin[x^2/2]}`

Now, we find their positions:

```
pos = Table[
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Position[flist, flistDD[[i]]]], {i, Length[flistDD]}]
```

> `{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}`

Meaning we have dependence of (this code is not necessary, just a showcase):

```
Transpose[{flistDD, pos}]
```

> `{{x^2 Cos[x^2/2] FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]], {1, 
>      2}}, {x Cos[x^2/2]^2 FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]], {3}}, {Sin[x^2/2], {4, 
>      5}}}`

Your gathering of terms is then finally given by:

```
Table[Part[f, pos[[i]]], {i, Length[flistDD]}] // Simplify
```

> `{(0.5 b + 3 c) x^2 Cos[a]^3 Cos[x^2/2] FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]], 
>    Sqrt[b] x Cos[a]^2 Cos[x^2/2]^2 FresnelC[x/Sqrt[b]] Sin[a], 
>    Cos[a] (Cos[a] + 0.5 Sin[a]) Sin[a] Sin[x^2/2]}`

If you want this as a function instead of a list add `//Total`.

### ADDENDUM

Suppose one term encompasses another, and we get a `pos` of

> `{{1, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}`

As we have reverse ordered the list, we need to eliminate later duplicates.

```
Table[Table[
  pos[[i]] = Complement[pos[[i]], pos[[j]]], {j, i - 1}], {i, 
  Length[flistDD]}];
pos
```

> `{{1, 5}, {3, 4}, {2}}`

And now we get:

```
Table[Part[f, pos[[i]]], {i, Length[flistDD]}] // Simplify
```

> `{-(1/4) b x^2 Cos[a]^2 Cos[x^2/2] (11 Cos[a] - Sin[a]), -(1/
>      4) (-2 + Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[b]
>      x Cos[a]^2 Cos[x^2/2] Sin[a], -(1/8) b Cos[a]^2 Cos[x^2/2] Sin[a]}`

Comment: You can use `MemberQ` instead of `Not@FreeQ`; and run `Total` in the last line to regain `f`.

Comment: @corey979 That was my first instinct too, but then you lose the special functions.

Comment: Yeah, I checked: `MemberQ` indeed doesn't work here.

Comment: Great, many thanks. However, do I need to know all the functions which appear beforehand? Can I just instruct it to group the terms together, without me knowing which are which?

Comment: I figured it - thank you so much.

Comment: @Morgan  If this answers your question consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: I was about to do it, but then I discovered that the code does not do exactly what I needed - I get terms like this:

Comment: -(1/8) Cos[x^2/
  2] (22 b x^2 Cos[a]^3 + b Cos[a]^2 Sin[a] - 
   4 Sqrt[b] x Cos[a]^2 Sin[a] + 
   2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b] x Cos[a]^2 Sin[a] - 2 b x^2 Cos[a]^2 Sin[a])

Which unfortunately collects several terms with different functional form in x. What I want is these to be separate, because I need to integrate the whole thing afterwards.

Comment: @Morgan, I understand why this goes wrong, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Morgan, should be fixed now, Please make sure you run `Expand[f]` first, there is new code under *Addendum* but some of the previous code has been changed too.

Comment: @corey979 Note the difference in the default level specs for `MemberQ` (`{1}`) and `FreeQ` (`{1, Infinity}`). (This is why your suggestion does not work as is.)

Comment: Hi Feyre, I have accepted your answer as correct, however I noticed that there is a small glitch: in the end I have one term which is -(1/4) Sin[3 a] Sin[(3 x^2)/2] and another 1/8 Sin[3 a] (Sin[x^2/2] - Sin[(3 x^2)/2]). Now clearly this shouldn't be the case, and terms with look-alike coefficients should not be grouped together. By the way, I run a product-to-sum formulae rule on the x-dependent terms before I apply your code.

Comment: @Morgan It's hard for me to iron out every detail when I don't have the complete data. Feel free to tweak the code and edit my post. Though I feel this could be prevented by running `Expand[]` first.

Comment: Dear Feyre, many thanks for your help. I tried but could not fix the code on my own. I have posted my complete function (prior to expand) in my original post. Could you please have a look? Thank you.

Comment: @Morgan I can't see a factor of `Sin[(3 x^2)/2]` or `Sin[3a]` in your example in the question. As far as I can tell your example code runs fine.

Comment: @Feyre, it runs fine, and almost all the terms are segregated as necessary, however I still get several like this one:

Comment: `-(1/8) b x^2 Cos[a]^3 Cos[x^2/2] - 1/4 Cos[a] Cos[2 a] Cos[x^2/2] + 
 1/2 Cos[a]^2 Sin[a] Sin[x^2] + 1/2 Cos[a] Cos[2 a] Sin[a] Sin[x^2] - 
 1/2 Sin[a]^3 Sin[x^2] - 1/2 Sin[a]^2 Sin[2 a] Sin[x^2]`

Comment: @Morgan, When I run your example code, the only terms with `Sin[x^2]` I get are `(1/2)*Cos[2*a]*Cos[x^2/2]*Sin[a]*Sin[x^2] - 
   (1/2)*Cos[a]*Cos[2*a]*Sin[x^2/2]*Sin[x^2]`

Comment: @Feyre Since I am looking for terms with a single trigonometric function, I apply product-to-sum relations to such terms - I am sorry I should have mentioned. There should be terms with Sin[x^2], others with x Sin[x^2], and others with x^2 Sin[x^2]. It is just that after I apply them, when I produce the list of different terms, there are many which are properly sorted, but others are combinations of terms with different x-dependence, which does not work for me. Again, thank you for lending so much time to this.

Comment: More specifically, I do the following, post applying Expand:

`SubExp[x_] = 
 Expandpos[x] /. {Sin[a] :> m, Cos[a] :> n, Sin[2 a] :> p, 
   Cos[2 a] :> q}`

`coscosProd = Cos[a_]*Cos[b_] :> (1/2) (Cos[a + b] + Cos[a - b])`
`cossinProd = Cos[a_]*Sin[b_] :> (1/2) (Sin[a + b] - Sin[a - b])`
`sinsinProd = Sin[a_]*Sin[b_] :> (1/2) (Cos[a - b] - Cos[a + b])`
`sinDouble = Sin[a_]^2 :> (1/2) (1 - Cos[2 a])`
`cosDouble = Cos[a_]^2 :> (1/2) (1 + Cos[2 a])`
`sinCubed = Sin[a_]^3 :> Sin[a] - Sin[a] Cos[a]^2`
`cosCubed = Cos[a_]^3 :> Cos[a] - Cos[a] Sin[a]^2`

Comment: `SubExp2[x_] = 
 SubExp[x] //. {coscosProd, cossinProd, sinsinProd, sinDouble, 
   cosDouble, sinCubed, cosCubed}`

`f = Expand[SubExp2[x]] /. {m :> Sin[a], n :> Cos[a], p :> Sin[2 a], 
   q :> Cos[2 a]}`

Comment: This way I get a single trigonometric factor in each term, and many of these are the same, so they need to be grouped.

Comment: @Morgan I can see this goes wrong. When I try your replacement rules *after* running my code, and then run my code *again* on that result, the issue doesn't seem to persist.

Comment: @Feyre I tried what you suggested - running your code, then running the replacement, then running your code again, but the issue is still there. There is an item on the list of the form 1/8 (-b x^2 Cos[a]^3 Cos[x^2/2] + 
   4 Cos[a]^2 Sin[a] Sin[x^2] + (-4 Sin[a]^3 + Sin[4 a]) Sin[x^2] - 
   2 Cos[a] (Cos[2 a] Cos[x^2/2] + 4 Sin[a]^3 Sin[x^2])) which is not very useful.